# plugins not working in custom theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development

I am creating a custom theme. In it I am trying to add salon booking plugin. This plugin creates default booking page. When I am viewing the booking page I cannot see the booking form. I have tried installing the salon booking plugin in WordPress default theme twenty twenty-one and it is working fine in this theme. Not sure what is breaking in my theme.

In my theme I have added `wp_head()` just before end of head tag in `header.php`. I have also added `wp_footer()` just before the end of body tag in footer.php.

I have following php files

- `header.php`
- `footer.php`
- `functions.php`
- `index.php`
- `front-page.php`

I have following pages - home page (that I created, this is pointing to front-page.php), Booking, Thank you for booking, Booking my account. Last three booking pages were created as part of the salon booking plugin.

`header.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes();?>>
<head>
    <meta charset=<?php bloginfo('charset');?>>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!--<title>Dust Doctors LLC Theme</title>-->
    <title><?php bloginfo('name');?></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/img/favicon.ico');?>">
    <?php /*include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' ); */?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    
</head>
<body <?php body_class();?> data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbarResponsive">

    <!-- Start Header Section -->
    <header id="home">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a href="#home" class="navbar-brand"><img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/img/logo.jpeg');?>" alt=""></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
                    <span class="custom-toggler-icon"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#aboutUs" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#services" class="nav-link">Our Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#clients" class="nav-link">Clients</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#book" class="nav-link">Book Now</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#faq" class="nav-link">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- End Navigation -->
    </header>
    <!-- End Header Section -->
```

`footer.php`:

```
<footer>
    
    <div class="container footer px-0">
        <hr class="socket">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <img src="img/logo.jpeg" alt="" class="brand__logo">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row outer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row py-3">
                    <!--<div class="col-md-6 px-0 pr-md-3">-->
                    <div class="col-md-4 px-0 pl-md-3">
                        <h5 class="text-theme util__margin__botom">Corporate Office</h5>
                        <p>
                            <i class="fas fa-map-marker"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;100 Street Name,<br>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Our City, <br>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AA 10000
                        </p>
                    </div> <!-- End Column -->
                    <div class="col-md-4 px-0 pl-md-3">
                        <h5 class="text-theme util__margin__botom">Contact Info</h5>
                        <p><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(888) 888-8888 <br>
                            <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;info@dustdoctorsllc.com <br>
                            <i class="fas fa-fax"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(888) 888-8888</p>
                            <h5 class="text-theme util__margin__botom">Follow Us On</h5>
                        <ul class="social">
                            <li><span><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></span></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square" ></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!---<div class="col-md-6 px-0 pr-md-3">-->
                        <div class="col-md-4 px-0 pl-md-3">
                            <h5 class="text-theme util__margin__botom">Useful Links</h5>
                            <i class="fas fa-link"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="footer__link">PRIVACY POLICY</a><br>
                            <i class="fas fa-link"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="footer__link">TERMS</a><br>
                            <i class="fas fa-link"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="footer__link">COMPANY</a><br>
                            <i class="fas fa-link"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="footer__link">SERVICES</a><br>
                        </div>                  
                </div> <!-- End Row -->
            </div> <!-- End Container -->

            <hr class="socket">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <p class="text-center">&copy; Dust Doctors LLC 2021</p>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- End Row Outer -->
    </div> <!-- End Container Fluid -->
    
</footer>
    <!-- Top Scroll -->
    <a href="#home" class="top-scroll">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>
    <!-- End of Top Scroll -->


    <!-- Script Source Files -->


    <!-- Plugins.js -->
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <!-- Waypoints https://cdnjs.com/libraries/waypoints
        https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Font Awesome https://fontawesome.com/  https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/js/all.js -->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/js/all.js"></script>
    <!-- Lightbox Image Gallery https://cdnjs.com/libraries/lightbox2  https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.1/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Owl Carousel https://cdnjs.com/libraries/OwlCarousel2
        http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery CounterUp https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/jquery.counterup
        https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up2 -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.counterup@2.1.0/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Form Validator https://cdnjs.com/libraries/1000hz-bootstrap-validator -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- End of Script Source Files -->
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

`index.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>



<?php get_footer();?>
```

`functions.php`:

```
<?php
    function theme_assets(){
        /*wp_enqueue_style('dust_doctors_main_styles',get_stylesheet_uri());*/
        /* bootstrap*/
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap','//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',array(),'v5.1.3',false);
        /* main css*/
        wp_enqueue_style('main_style',get_theme_file_uri('/css/style.css'),array('bootstrap'),'1.0',false);
        /* plugins css*/
        wp_enqueue_style('plugins_style',get_theme_file_uri('/css/plugins.css'),array(),'1.0',false);
        /* google fonts*/
        wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts','//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700&display=swap',array(),'1.0',false);
        /* animate css*/
        wp_enqueue_style('animate-css','//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css',array(),'v3.7.2',false);
        /* lightbox*/
        wp_enqueue_style('lightbox','//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.1/css/lightbox.min.css',array(),'v2.11.1',false);
         /* owl carousel */
         wp_enqueue_style('owlcarousel1','//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css',array(),'v2.3.4',false);
         wp_enqueue_style('owlcarousel2','//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css',array(),'v2.3.4',false);
         /* jquery */
         wp_enqueue_script('boot-jquery','//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js',array('jquery'),'',false);
         /* bootstrap popper js*/
         wp_enqueue_script('boot-popper-js','//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js',array('jquery'),'v1.14.7',false);
         /* bootstrap main js*/
         wp_enqueue_script('boot-main-js','//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js',array('jquery'),'v4.3.1',false);
         /* main js script*/
         wp_enqueue_script('plugin-js',get_theme_file_uri('/js/plugins.js'),array('jquery','jquery-ui-core','jquery-ui-selectmenu'),'1.0',true);
         /* waypoints*/ 
         wp_enqueue_script('waypoints','//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js',array('jquery'),'v4.0.1',true);
         /* font awesome */
         wp_enqueue_script('font-awesome','//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/js/all.js',array(),'v5.13.0',true);
         /* lightbox */
         wp_enqueue_script('lightbox-js','//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.1/js/lightbox.min.js',array('jquery'),'v2.11.1',true);
         /* owl carousel */
         wp_enqueue_script('owl-carousel-js','/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js',array('jquery'),'v2.3.4',true);
         /* counter js */
         wp_enqueue_script('counter-js','//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.counterup@2.1.0/jquery.counterup.min.js',array('jquery'),'v2.1.0',true);
         /* form validator*/
         wp_enqueue_script('form-validator','//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js',array('jquery'),'v0.11.9',true);
       
    }

    /* change login logo in wp-admin*/
    function my_login_logo() { ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            body.login{
                background-image:url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/slide-02.jpeg);
                background-size: cover;
                background-position: center center;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
            }
            #login h1 a, .login h1 a {
                background-image: url(<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.jpeg);
            height:150px;
            width:150px;
            background-size: 150px 150px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
                padding-bottom: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    <?php }

    function my_login_logo_url() {
        return home_url();
    }

    function my_login_logo_url_title() {
        return 'Dust Doctors LLC Login';
    }

    function add_site_favicon() {
        echo '<link rel="shortcut icon"
    href="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/favicon.ico" />';
    }
    

        /*function custom_unregister_theme_post_types() {
            global $wp_post_types;
        
              if ( isset( $wp_post_types["image"] ) ) {
                 unset( $wp_post_types[ "image" ] ); //UPDATED
              }
        
        }
        add_action( 'init', 'custom_unregister_theme_post_types', 20 );*/
        
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_assets');
    add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );
    add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'my_login_logo_url' );
    add_filter( 'login_headertext', 'my_login_logo_url_title' );
    add_action('login_head', 'add_site_favicon');
    add_action('admin_head', 'add_site_favicon');
?>
```

`front-page.php`:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    
    <?php 
    //custom fields
    $landing_background_image = get_field('landing_background_image');
    $landing_header = get_field('landing_header');
    if (empty($landing_header)){
        $landing_header = 'looking for a cleaning service?';
    }
    $landing_tag_line = get_field('landing_tag_line');
    if (empty($landing_tag_line)){
        $landing_tag_line = 'we are here to make your home shine';
    }
    if (empty($landing_button)){
        $landing_button = "let's shine";
    }
    ?>
    
    
        <!-- Start Landing Page Section -->
        <section>
            <!-- Start Landing Page Image and Title -->
            <div class="landing">
                <div class="home-wrap">
                    <!--<div class="home-inner"></div>-->
                    <ul class="home-slideshow">
                    <li>
                        <?php if(!empty($landing_background_image)){?>
                            <span style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(11,12,16,0.7) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url(<?php echo $landing_background_image['url'];?>)">Image 01</span>
                        <?php } else{?>
                            <span style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(11,12,16,0.7) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url(<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/img/slide-02.jpeg');?>)">Image 01</span>
                        <?php }?>
                <!--        <div class="slide__title text-center text-uppercase">
                        <h1 class="slide__title__main">looking for a cleaning service?</h1>
                        <h3 class="slide__title__sub">we are here to make your home shine</h3>-->
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Landing Page Image and Title-->
    
            <!-- Start Landing Page Button -->
            <div class="caption text-center text-light text-uppercase">
                <!--<h1 class="caption__title__main os-animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="1s">looking for a cleaning service?</h1>
                <h3 class="caption__title__sub os-animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="2s">we are here to make your home shine</h3>
                <a href="#booking" class="btn btn__primary btn__animated os-animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="3s">let's shine</a>-->
                <h1 class="caption__title__main os-animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="1s"><?php echo $landing_header;?></h1>
                <h3 class="caption__title__sub os-animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="2s"><?php echo $landing_tag_line;?></h3>
                <a href="#booking" class="btn btn__primary btn__animated os-animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="3s"><?php echo $landing_button;?></a>
            </div>
            <!-- End Landing Page Button -->
    
            <!-- Start Bouncing Down Arrow -->
            <a href="#aboutUs" class="down-arrow text-center">
                <!--<div class="arrow d-none d-md-block">-->
                <div class="arrow">
                    <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                </div>
            </a>
            <!-- End Bouncing Down Arrow -->
        </section>
        <!-- End Landing Page Section -->
    
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: I do not see a main loop or calls to `have_posts`/`the_post`/`the_content` anywhere in your files, so there are no opportunities to show any content in the theme

Comment: Otherwise, you need to contact Salon booking plugin support, or ask in their communities, 3rd party plugin support questions are off topic here

Comment: Thanks a ton. I now created two new php files page.php and single.php with following content and the issue got resolved. 
 <?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="generic-content">
        <?php the_content();?>
    </div>

<?php get_footer();?>

Comment: you should post that as an answer below rather than a comment so the site knows you've found your solution, and others with this issue can learn from you. I'd also advise calling `the_post` and `the_content`, and ensuring your theme has a proper main post loop to avoid other issues

Answer (score 1):

Your theme does not contain a main post loop, so there is no place for the plugin to do its work

```php
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
        the_content();
    } // end while
} // end if
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a ton. I now created two new php files page.php and single.php with following content and the issue got resolved.

```
    <div class="generic-content"> <?php the_content();?> </div>
```

Comment: You need to read the documentation and look at the default themes to see how themes are supposed to be built. This might be sufficient for this plugin but it’s still not correct.